# Boilerplates for infyOm cannot setup the DataTables [Laravel 6.0 using AdminLTE Boilerplate]

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, infyom

I am using Laravel 6.0 for this project. I cannot set up the DataTables properly when using InfyOm's Boilerplate. I've followed the documentation part [which is here](https://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/6.0/boilerplates) regarding the boilerplate and run `composer install` on the terminal.

After finishing, I then created a sample scaffold CRUD in order to see if the DataTables worked. And it didn't work. It only displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKVgt.jpg) after creating a sample data for the CRUD.

I then check infyOm's documentation regarding the Datatable. But before that, I run a `php artisan infyom:rollback Test scaffold` to rollback the previously created scaffold.

I then followed [this](https://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/6.0/generator-options#datatables) documentation regarding the setup for DataTable. I've installed the 3 mentioned packages—DataTables, DataTable Button Pluging, and the HTML plugin.

After installing the 3 packages, I then change the `'add_on.datatables' => false` into `true` in the `config/infyom/laravel_generator.php` file and inserted the necessary `providers` and `aliases` within the `config/app.php` file. I then run a `php artisan config:clear` command and run another `php artisan infyom:scaffold` command.

But still, the Datatables still doesn't work.

Did I make a mistake on installing the DataTables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that I need to run a `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=datatables-buttons` after all of the mentioned steps. Datatables now works fine.